# Setting defined constants (icons) from a database

Tags: php, mysql

I use icons in a variety of dynamic ways and store them in a database.

```
function icon($id){

   $result = $db->select('SELECT icon FROM icons WHERE icon_id= :i LIMIT 1',
   array('i' => $id));

   if(count($result) == 0) return '--';

   return $result[0]['icon'];
}
```

However this can result in many queries per page when lots of icons appear.
So I thought maybe to set them as constant as there is never going to be more than a 100 or so..

```
function icon($icon){
    if (!defined('SITE_ICONS')){
        $result = $db->select('SELECT icon, icon_id FROM icons');
        foreach($result as $i){
            define('ICON'.$i['icon_id'], $i['icon']);
        }
     define('SITE_ICONS', 'Y');
    } 

     if (defined('ICON'.$icon)){ 
          return constant('ICON'.$icon);
     }
}
```

Is this just overcomplicating things and is there a limit to how many items can be defined this way? Or should I be exploring things like memcache?

Comment: You might consider a caching strategy in your case.

Comment: are the icon values strings?

Comment: I'm using material icons so only return the keyword eg., 'menu' `<span class="material-icons">'.icon(12).'</span> `